# mobile web service does not work

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, yii

I'm building a site using Yii framework ,website has been developed to working in browsers *PC* and to run it using mobile browser .i will now put you in the scope .

- i made a webservice which bring the text of the message from the sms table in my database .
  here is the webservice :

mobile.php:

```
   getSMS( function(jsonResponse) {

    var msg = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);

    document.getElementById('term').value=(msg[hold-1]['text']);


   });
```

also there is the soap.js file and webservice.php but there is no need to give you the
    code. 
this web service has been tested and successfully working . if you open the website using PC browser like chrome ,its working , but if you open the page using mobile browser (it does not work).

don't misunderstand it , i don't need code , look for my question first :

my question is : is there any difference if you run a webservice (in general) between mobile browser or PC browser ? if yes give me reasons ?

Answer (score 1):

In generally - no (if it the newest mobile browsers on iOS or Android - their must compatible all new technologies: HTML5, WebSockets and other). I don't what compatible Symbian standart browser
I found (but don't learning) some mini research in http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html. The main difference is `UserAgent` of mobile browsers, here its' list http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/. In order of user agent the website knew what version of site (mobile or desktop) show. 

**For cleary testing** you may set on Chrome (for example) manual user agent one of the mobile browser ([here](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/12/changing-user-agent-new-google-chrome.html) one of examples)